# OpenCV estimate distance & normal vector from homography

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm matching a template from which I know my distance to & my normal vector to.

i.e. if my homography is the identity matrix then my camera is at Distance = 1.0m & my normal is at 0.

Now I have a second image in which I successfully aligned my template giving an homography:

```
     [0.82072, 0.05685, 66.75024]
 H = [0.02006, 0.86092, 39.34907]
     [0.00003, 0.00017, 01.00000]
```

I also have my camera matrix.

the opencv function :

```
cv::decomposeHomographyMat()
```

gives me 4 solutions for the Rotation(3x3 mat),Translation(3x1 mat) & Normal vector(3x1).

```
cv::warpPerspective()
```

Is able to map nearly perfectly the current view of the camera to my template.

So it should be possible to get the actual scaling (template to alignment) & the normal vector.

But I can't figure it out how to actually choose the correct solutions of cv::decomposeHomographyMat(), I'm I missing something?

EDIT: Posted "question" without the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out.

Step one:

I create a set of point in the ROI I can map to my template (points in the area defined by the corners of the ROI).

Step two:

Warp the points in ROI (from step one; 8 points are enough in all my tests & use case) with all the solutions of cv::decomposeHomographyMat()

Exclude all solutions that give a point3D(x, y, z) with a z value < 0 (i.e. point is behind the camera).

Step three:

At this point you should have one to two solutions left.
All rotations matrixes should be the same, only the normal & translation matrix should differ.

Translations matrixes should verify:

```
Translation_Solution1 = -1* Translation_Solution2
```

Then compare your ROI area to you template area.
If you ROI area is smaller than your template, it means that you template as been "scaled down", i.e. your camera did a translation on z in the negative values.
Else you camera did a translation on the positive z values.

Chose the appropriate solution.

My error was to think that warpPerspective() was actually solving the Homography decomposition, but its not.

Comment: Will it be possible to get the absolute translation from this decomposition procedure on a 2D plane? I would much appreciate if you could show me a sample work that I can follow.

Thanking You!

Comment: it is possible, create a question and link it, comment aren't the good place for that.

Comment: I've asked this question a while a go. Thank you very much for being interested. This is the link I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264004/finding-most-suitable-rotation-and-translation-from-homography-decomposition

Answer (score 2):

in paper Faugeras O D, Lustman F. Motion and structure from motion in a piecewise planar environment.1988 page 9 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243764888_Motion_and_Structure_from_Motion_in_a_Piecewise_Planar_Environment
[image]

Comment: Textual representation of the text parts of that paper (or better a summary of the most relevant part) would be preferred. Think for example of those people who use StackOverflow via a screen reader.

Comment: Thanks SuJie, this text helped me to understand how to choose the right solution.